# Python Selenium Upload photo to Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I have tried so many times trying to upload a photo to a Facebook post. When I read the selenium documents all it says was

> Select the `<input type="file">` element and call the `send_keys()` method passing the file path, either the path relative to the test script, or an absolute path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

usr = "random@gmail.com"
pwd = "randompassword"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/login")
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#u_0_y")
elem.send_keys("Hello Internet :) ")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._11b").click()
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What goes wrong?

Comment: what´s the use case for this?

Comment: The use is that i want to program a bot that can post images and messages at set time intervals,i am not interested in api usage and would like to gain an intimate understanding of how to build bots for any website

Answer (score 2):

This works for me..

```
def main():
    # Your Facebook account user and password
    usr = "test.fb.post@gmail.com"
    pwd = "test123456789"





     grp = ['https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/', 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/',
           'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/', 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/',
            'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/', 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/',
           'https://www.facebook.com/groups/grpid/']





    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2  # 1:allow, 2:block
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)  # seconds

    # Go to facebook.com
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
    sleep(2)
    # Enter user email
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    elem.send_keys(usr)
    # Enter user password
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
    elem.send_keys(pwd)
    # Login
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(10)
    for group in grp:

        driver.get(group)

        try:

            try:

                commentr = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( (By.XPATH, "//*[@name='xhpc_message_text']") ))
                commentr.click()

            except Exception:
                commentr = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( (By.XPATH, "//*[@loggingname='status_tab_selector']") ))
                commentr.click()



            commentr = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_3u15']") ))
            commentr.click()

            sleep(3)
            l=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input') 
            sleep(1)

            for g in l: 
                if g==driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][@class='_n _5f0v']"): 
                    sleep(1)
                    g.send_keys(ipath) 
                    print('image loaded')




            sleep(10)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_1mf _1mj']").send_keys(message)

            sleep(1)
            buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
            sleep(1)
            for button in buttons:
                    if button.text == "Post":
                        sleep(5)
                        button.click()
                        sleep(10)

        except Exception:
            pass
            print ('image not posted in '+group)


    driver.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using css_selector, try using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

statuselement=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@name='xhpc_message']").click() driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@class='_3jk']").click() l=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input') ipath="C:\Users\Utente\Pictures\CoutureBeardsley.jpg" for g in l: if g==driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file'][@class='_n _5f0v']"): g.send_keys(ipath) print('image loaded')

Comment: At first glance this looks totally unrelated to the original question. I recommend editing it to give context or include OP's parameters.